# Duvida sobre padrão classe React

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou começando o meus primeiros passos com o React, gostaria de saber por que não está sendo criado a class no react, quando executo o comando `npx create-react-app` cria a estrutura abaixo.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Minha duvida é, porque o React não cria a estrutura padrão como abaixo?**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code> src/App.js</code> ande save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"

                    Learn React
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;**
```

**Utilizei os seguintes comandos:**

```js
npm install -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app nome-app
```

**Como posso manter essa estrutura?**

Comment: A resposta foi satisfatória?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Minha duvida é, porque o React não cria a estrutura padrão como abaixo?

Deve estar usando a versão mais recente do [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs)(*Versão:* <kbd>>=16.8</kbd>) que  apresenta os [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). [A grande motivação para essa adoação é para solucionar problemas no desenvolvimento de componentes](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation).

[Hooks permite o uso de estado e recursos do ReactJs sem escrever classes](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) e no seu site relata os problemas:

- [É Difícil Reutilizar Lógica com Estado entre Componentes](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#its-hard-to-reuse-stateful-logic-between-components)
- [Componentes Complexos se Tornam Difíceis de Entender](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#complex-components-become-hard-to-understand)
- [Classes Confundem tanto Pessoas quanto Máquinas](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#classes-confuse-both-people-and-machines)

Tudo isso aconteceu na criação desse primeiro componente em base no template inicial, mas, se quiser pode criar os componentes baseados em classes, inclusive as duas formas funcionam e podem coexistir no mesmo projeto, mas, todavia é melhor escolher se quer tudo classe ou [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), ter essa mistura muitas vezes atrapalha em manutenções futuras.

> Como posso manter essa estrutura?

No momento da instalação o template é o mais recente (***versão mais atual***) e por isso é com [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), mas, como já relatei é só transformar a função para classe se assim preferir continuar com desenvolvimento com classes, mas, isso agora é com você.

Código implementado com Classes

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this);
  }
  handleIncrement() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Código implementado com [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```js
function Source() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const handleIncrement = () => setCount(count + 1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>{count}</div>
        <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Source/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

É nitido que no desenvolvimento com classes o código é maior (verboso), cheio de regras que devem ser seguidas e com [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) o código é simples, fácil de entender e de dar manutenção. Lembro que as duas formas tem a mesma saída e que nada impede continuar com classes, [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) é um jeito melhor de desenvolver e trazer uma maneira clara um componente em [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs)

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Introdução aos Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
- [React v16.8: O React com Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html)
- [Hooks de forma resumida](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)
- [Usando o State do Hook](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
- [Usando Effect Hook (Hook de Efeito)](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
- [Regras dos Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)
- [Criando seus próprios Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)
- [API de Referência dos Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)
- [Hooks FAQ](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html)