# problemas com o this em ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web, react, front-end

O problema é o seguinte: estou tentando construir um contador pra praticar o meu `React` e ocorreu um erro:

> `this is undefined`

Eu criei um state pra guardar os minutos e os segundos:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        min: 0,
        seg: 0,
    }
}
```

Chamei os dois lá no meu render:

```
render() {
    const { min, seg } = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <p>{min}:{seg}</p>
            <button onClick={this.startCountdown}>Start</button>
            <button>Stop</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

e depois e fui criar a função para iniciar a contagem. Vejam, à princípio **eu não quero a lógica de decrementação**, eu tava tentando simplesmente mudar os valores na tela ao clicar em `startCowndown`, mas eu tive o retorno do erro `this is undefined`.

A minha função pra mudar os valores na tela ficou assim:

```
startCountdown () {
    let {min, seg} = this.state;
    this.setState({min: 1, seg: 59})
}
```

Bem, não funcionou, então eu achei que seria desnecessário chamar min e seg com o destructuring já que eu já estava usando o método `setState`, então tirei.

```
startCountdown(){
    this.setState({min: 1, seg: 59})
}
```

e mesmo assim **this is undefined** continua a aparecer.

Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê desse comportamento?

Comment: faltou a arrow function.  `<button onClick={() => this.startCountdown}>Start</button>` e no método `startCountdown () => {...`

Comment: e outra não precisa fazer o descruct, método correto `startCountdown () => {
    this.setState({min: 1, seg: 59})
}`

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha com hooks https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hugle-hq4x5

Comment: as soluções de vocês estão perfeitas, mas nenhuma funcionou nem funcionaria mesmo, justamente porque eu estava chamando a função onClick não numa tag, mas no componente Button. <Button onClick={startPomodoro}/> Depois que eu fiz a chamada dentro da tag todas as soluções apresentadas passaram a funcionar.

Comment: que contradição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antônio,

Estranho ocorrer erro dizendo que o contexto `this` está indefinido. Precisava ver o código completo.

No entanto, fiz um sandbox implementando exatamente o que você deseja atingir, você pode dar uma analisada e verificar o que pode esta errado.

https://codesandbox.io/s/contador-eops1

Uma coisa importante a se lembrar é o fato de usar o `bind`. Para que uma function dentro de uma classe tenha o mesmo contexto da classe, para ter acesso ao state, por exemplo, é necessário utilizar um método chamado `bind`.

Veja só o código dentro do construtor:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.startCountdown = this.startCountdown.bind(this);
}

state = {
 min: 0,
 seg: 0
};

startCountdown() {
 this.setState({ min: 1, seg: 59 });
}
```

O código está funcionando agora.

Qualquer dúvida, comente essa resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Porque o erro aconteceu?

Quanto você trabalha com classes em `react`, os métodos em `react` precisam dizer em qual contexto pertence e com `bind(this)` resolve esse problema. Existe formas de resolver isso, um delas é pelo `constructor` ou até mesmo fazer no próprio botão ou componente, exemplo:

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this);
  }
  handleIncrement() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

ou no próprio `onClick`:

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };    
  }
  handleIncrement() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement.bind(this)}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

ou até declara uma função anônima que simplifica e não tem que utilizar o `bind(this)`:

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };  
  }
  handleIncrement = () => {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    this.setState({ count });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

No seu código eu faria assim:

```js
class Source extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        min: 0,
        seg: 0,
    }
    this.startCountdown =
      this.startCountdown.bind(this);
  }
  startCountdown () {
    let {min, seg} = this.state;
    this.setState({min: 1, seg: 59})
  }
  render() {
    const { min, seg } = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <p>{min}:{seg}</p>
            <button onClick={this.startCountdown}>Start</button>
            <button>Stop</button>
            <button>Reset</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render( <Source/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Pronto funcionou.

[No atual momento utilizamos mais Hooks que simplifica esse processo dê uma olhada na sintaxe escrita por essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426304/duvida-sobre-padr%C3%A3o-classe-react/426335#426335)